# R: For loop on list of dataframes to output matrices of matches among each combination of levels of a factor

Tags: r, matrix

I have a dataframe like so:

```
region     plot    species
 1          1A      A_B  
 1          1B      B_C
 1          1C      A_B
 1          1D      C_D
 2          2A      B_C
 2          2A      E_F
 2          2B      B_C
 2          2B      E_F     
 2          2C      E_F
 2          2D      B_C
 3          3A      A_B
 3          3B      A_B
```

This dataframe goes on for thousands of rows, so I would like to use a loop to:
 1) subset the data by region 
 2) and then create matrices for all pairwise comparisons of the plots 
    within each subsetted region.

In this case, i and j dimensions of the matrix are the plot ID within the region and the matrix fill includes counts of shared species combinations. The unfilled half of the matrix would be filled with NAs. These matrices will be put into a list. For this example, the result would be:

```
resultslist<-
[[1]]      1A   1B    1C    1D    

         1A NA   NA   NA   NA   NA

         1B 0   NA    NA   NA   NA

         1C 1   0    NA    NA   NA

         1D 0   0    0    NA    NA

 [[2]]       2A   2B    2C    2D    

         2A NA   NA   NA   NA   NA

         2B 2   NA    NA   NA   NA

         2C 1   1    NA    NA   NA

         2D 1   1    0    NA    NA


[[3]]      3A   3B       

         3A NA   NA   

         3B 1   NA
```

Here is the loop I have tried:

```
data<- subset(file, select = c(region,plot, species))

sublist=NA
 for (i in unique(data$region)){   
  sublist[i]<-list(subset(data, data[,1] == i))  
  print(i)
 }

results = list()

for (i in 1: length(unique(sublist))){ 
    output<- matrix(0, nrow = length(plot), ncol = length(plot))
    plot_i<-unique(sublist[[i]][[2]])
    plot_j<-unique(sublist[[i]][[2]])
    output[i,j]<-length(intersect(plot_i$species, plot_j$species))

 results[[i]]=output
     }
results
```

Answer (score 0):

I went on with your code and came up with this:

**The data:**

```
data=read.table(text="region     plot    species
1          1A      A_B  
1          1B      B_C
1          1C      A_B
1          1D      C_D
2          2A      B_C
2          2A      E_F
2          2B      B_C
2          2B      E_F     
2          2C      E_F
2          2D      B_C
3          3A      A_B
3          3B      A_B",stringsAsFactors=F,h=T)
```

**The code:**

```
sublist=NA
for (i in unique(data$region)){   
  sublist[i]<-list(subset(data, data[,1] == i))  
  print(i)
}

results = list()
for (r in unique(data$region)){
  myset<-split(sublist[[r]][[3]],sublist[[r]][[2]])
  output<- matrix(NA, nrow = length(myset), ncol = length(myset))
  rownames(output)<-colnames(output)<-unique(sublist[[r]][[2]])
  for (j in 1:(length(myset)-1)){
    for (i in (j+1):length(myset)){
       output[i,j]=sum(myset[[j]] %in% myset[[i]])
    }
  }
results[[r]]=output
}
```

**The output:**

```
[[1]]
   1A 1B 1C 1D
1A NA NA NA NA
1B  0 NA NA NA
1C  1  0 NA NA
1D  0  0  0 NA

[[2]]
   2A 2B 2C 2D
2A NA NA NA NA
2B  2 NA NA NA
2C  1  1 NA NA
2D  1  1  0 NA

[[3]]
   3A 3B
3A NA NA
3B  1 NA
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. This code worked great when I used the example data I provided to you. However, when using it on my actual data I get the following error: Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = 66L) :  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent Any idea why this may be? Also, one minor correction to the code you provided for sake of consistency, on the 7th line of the code: for (r in unique(df$region))the "df" should be changed to "data". @GyB

Comment: Hm, hard to tell without seeing the data. Can you try changing the line where you define the rownames to this: `rownames(output)<-colnames(output)<-names(myset)` ?

Comment: And thank you for the correction, I have edited the line

Comment: No, thank you for helping me here.`rownames(output)<-colnames(output)<-names(myset)` did provide an output, however it returned matrices with region 14 plot names.

Comment: I think I may have narrowed down  the possible source of error...the dataframe I am using has some instances where a particular region has only 1 plot associated with it (e.g. region 5 has only Plot 5A ). Therefore, a pairwise matrix would only include a pairwise comparison of Plot 5A against Plot 5A. Could this be the source of error? In that case, is it necessary to include an if else statement in the loop?

Comment: Indeed, if you have only one plot in a particular region, that could be a problem for the for loop. You can include something like `if (length(myset)>1){ and here the double for-loop }`